# XRDP bind only to eth0 adapter?

Tags: xrdp

The port configuration for xrdp specifies how to only bind to a port on a specific ip.
e.g. `port=tcp://192.168.1.1:3389`

But I plan on changing the physical adapters and IPs when I migrate the vm. Is there a convenient way to have it only bind to whatever IP eth0 happens to be?

UPDATE
I'm curious if maybe the solution would be to specify port forwarding in the firewall to redirect and have xrdp bind to localhost instead.

Answer (score 0):

Default xrdp configuration is *allow access from everywhere through 3389 port* despite network adapter and ip host has:

```
port=3389
```

I think, default configuration should work if you don't want to restrict access to only your network address:

```
$ cat /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini

[globals]
bitmap_cache=yes
bitmap_compression=yes
port=3389
crypt_level=low
channel_code=1
max_bpp=24

[xrdp1]
name=sesman-Xvnc
lib=libvnc.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
```

Configuration you specified `port=tcp://192.168.1.1:3389` I tried to change to `port=tcp://192.168.2.0:3389` or other non-existent machine's IP or network address. But xrdp pays no attention to it. It means, xrdp just ignores that.

Comment: Yes, that's how I have it configured now, but I'd like to bind it to the first ethernet adapter, regardless of the IP, so I can reuse this vm and have it bind automatically no matter what new adapter and IP I give it; but I want to bind it to the adapter so it doesn't bind to any other secondary IPs.